# ItemRealized event does not fire

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I wanna create a infinite longlistselector, but my event `ItemRealized` does not fire. i have create view model so i can generate an observable collection, and everything sees to be working fine when i monitoring the main class, i'm sure that it is not empty, but my problem is that i can not populate the longlistselector

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <vm:GoogleView x:Key="viewModel"/>        
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

longlistselector

```
            <phone:LongListSelector ItemRealized="m_ListBoxGoogle_ItemRealized"  Name="m_ListGoogle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="410" Margin="0,120,0,0"                             
             ItemsSource="{Binding GoogleCollection}" 
             DataContext="{StaticResource viewModel}">               
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Tag="{Binding GoogleID}" Style="{StaticResource NoVisualTextButton }" toolkit:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True" Click="OnListBoxItemClick" Margin="-10,0,0,0">
                            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,3,0,0" Height="auto" Width="450">
                                <Border BorderThickness="1" Width="62" Height="62" BorderBrush="#00aef0" Background="#00aef0">
                                    <Image  Height="60" Width="60" Source="{Binding GoogleImagePath}"/>
                                </Border>
                                <StackPanel Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,0,0,0" >
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding GoogleDisplayName}"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PanoramaItemTextStyle }" FontSize="24"  />
                                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding GoogleObjectType}"  TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PanoramaItemTextStyle }" FontSize="20" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>          
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>
```

i'm really stuck guys, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these things for I believe its a binding issue:

1. Debug and put a breakpoint in the GoogleView constructor and verify
   it is being instantiated.
2. If it is being instantiated verify the data you are binding to exists within the class.
3. If everything instantiated, try binding to the collection as TwoWay binding mode.
4. If that doesn't work try binding to the data in another control to verify things are working properly.

Comment: i'm so confused everything should be working fine, but still nothing, maybe today is not my day

Comment: @radoslaf Can you put a breakpoint in the GoogleView constructor and see 1) if its bein instantiated poperly and 2) if the data is actually being put in there where you expect it. Can you bind something else to the data which could confirm the data?